# How to fix spacing between tags and tumblr posts?

Tags: html, css, tags, tumblr

I'm using the feather 2.0 theme on tumblr https://www.tumblr.com/theme/36403 and I wanted to add tags to my posts. I found the answer here, to add

```
{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags}
<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

within the posts block. (I put it right before {/block:posts}) The problem with this is that the tags are really far below the post, like the line above the very next post. Also the colors are weird? Not fitting in with the theme colors.

Image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejw5k.png]

So the blue and purple words at the top are my tags from the previous post, and the purple words at the bottom are the tags from the text post about being tired.

Let me know if I need to include any more code.

Comment: Might need to see some more html css. Basically, you could add class to the tag link <a href="{TagURL}" class="tag-link">{Tag}</a> and then you could style the class in the style tags in the head of the doc. So something like a.tag-link {color:#333; margin:0;} a.tag-link:hover {color:#777;} etc. If you want this in an answer let me know.

Comment: @lharby what I'm most worried about is the spacing. Do you know how to make the tags come up, closer to the post?

Comment: There are a few things you can do. you might need to post some code though or show us a page, if you are using the theme exactly as it is currently then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In the theme you are using there is a wrapper for the tag information, in addition there is a margin applied to post paragraphs. In the css change :

```
.postmeta {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.post p {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
```

}

To

```
.postmeta {
   margin:0;
}

.post p {
   margin:0;
}
```

You will need to add this in the style tag at the top of the document.

If you get other issues, please add them here or to the original question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble finding that section. I just see a chunk of text like 
        `#content .post .postmeta a, #content .post .postmeta a:link, #content .post .postmeta a:visited { color: {color:Postmeta}; }`

Comment: Are you OK using the console/inspector in Chrome/Firefox/Safari?

Comment: http://theme.fm/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/chrome-inspector-twenty-eleven.png bottom right shows information about the styles being applied and any remote files applying these styles. In the theme listed the style is being applied in a file that has been uploaded to tumblr: http://static.tumblr.com/anfpypi/cp4mbbi94/feather_2.0_min.css
That contains the style information I listed in my answer. So you have write a block of code that overwrites the parent style. 
If you add it to the head of the document inside the style tags this will work. Maybe you should try it for fun.